# Autofocus input modal doesn't work inside Ng-Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap

consider the following [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krs5by), I'm developing an angular application 6 with Ng-Bootstrap and I have the following problem:

I have two components: the `modal component` and the `calendar component`. the modal component has an input that when the modal starts, the input is auto-focused. When I call my modal component from a button, the input auto-focus perfectly. The problem occurs when the modal component is called from the calendar component, that is, the modal component is inside the calendar component. When selecting a calendar date, the modal is opened but the entry is not auto-focused. My question is why when the modal component is called from the calendar component, the input does not auto-focus, but I do call my modal component from a button if it works. What is the explanation for this behavior?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Using  Life cycle hook **AfterViewChecked**:

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krs5by-ckgrv6)

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Comment: Many thanks, but why in the console shows this error: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'focused: true'. Current value: 'focused: false'.

Comment: It is due to Ng-Datepicker. when you focus on input it was focused than blur . you manually need to set it blur().